# Color of regular blue ballpoint

Tags: pantone, color-reproduction

I have an InDesign document typed with a handwriting font. I want to make the color of this font as close to the color of my ballpoint pen as possible.

Does ink colors that are used for ballpoint pens have corresponding Pantone names, so that I can narrow my search to 9-10 colors (that is, to 9-10 specific Pantone colors) over Web?

Comment: Why does it *have* to be a specific blue? Anyone reading things isn't going to dig up a blue ball point and match colors. *And*, there's not going to be any tactile depression where the blue type is, so it's *never* going to look like it's manually written on each print. I typically use anything which *looks* appropriate.

Comment: There are results when searching "Bic Pen Pantone" but I didn't see any official colors or documentation used for pens. I think the design is more important than the color used to create the handwritten effect.

Comment: @Scott This document is a "template" for my personal documents. I'm not going to share them with other people, I simply want the color that will resemple real pen so that it will be easier for ***me*** to focus on writing my ideas instead of nitpicking to grammar, punctuation, formatting and so on. When I use real pen and paper, it is easy to focus. When I start using computer, I begin nitpicking.

Comment: Screens vary if they are not color calibrated. And ballpoints don't all have the exact same color. The paper you write on also has an influence. The background color on your screen might be completely white and should be adjusted to look more like paper. I would just eye ball it (pen intended). Personally I write in a simple text editor with something like Courier or Consolas. Looks "neutral" to me. Like a typewriter.

Comment: What is close? What is you tolerance? How are you going to measure it? With what tool? What is the calculation used for color distace? Is you monitor known to be calibrated? This month, week, day, hour? Is your printer calibrated? Do you have a standard viewing environment? What exact pen and ink brand are you using? What is their color tolerance? How does the ink age? What paper is reference? Do you have a spectrometer? What is your reference whitebalance (different latitudes and times of year prime human senses differently)...

Answer (score 1):

Basic Ballpoint pens normally are not pms matched. However, Pantone™ markers are and come in fine points. My basic ballpoint is pms 2755, I just selected the closest color from a pms swatchbook and it is a near perfect match.

Comment: But monitors display RGB, not Pantone ink. Is it to be converted using the Lab color in Adobe's color books or should you use the RGB color given by Pantone? How does this Pantone color look on the OP's monitor? And do you mean the coated or uncoated swatch? (Sorry to be nitpicking )

Comment: I love nitpicking. It is hard to be a professional without nitpicking again and again.

Comment: He asked for a Pantone color so I assume it's offset printing. Pantone numbers are the same ink whether printed on coated or uncoated I slected from a matte book. It makes no difference because I don't know what substrate he's using. If you want to be nitpicky to get an accurate match you would have to print the color on the actual substrate because it would not match any book.

Comment: You are right. I commented because of the comment the OP made: "I'm not going to share them with other people, I simply want the color that will resemple real pen so that it will be easier for me to focus on writing my ideas". So it seems it's just for the OP's monitor. And my point just is: Then there is no "scientific" way - just eyeball it.